# Can I use System.Windows.Rect in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, .net

I need to work with a Rect that has Left, Top, Bottom, Right.

Unity's Rect has x, y, width and height instead.

Also, Unity's Rect doesn't accept `Rect.Compare(otherRect)`.

`System.Windows.Rect` however seems a good choice for my needs.

I would like to ask if it's ok to use `System.Windows.Rect` in my Unity script and if it will be cross-platform.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did your testing suggest that this could pose a problem?

Comment: I took a look at the docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect.contains?view=netframework-4.8. It showed "WindowsBase.dll", and I wondered what happens if my app runs on Android. I have not tried anything yet,

Comment: Test it on your target hardware, then post here if you determine there's a problem you need to solve.

Comment: :-) It might take 5 years until I release my first game. But then I will post the results here. :-)

Comment: You don't need to release your game to do a test. All you need is a friend with an Android.

Comment: But I want to target all other platforms as well. Even WiiU. That is why I was hoping somebody would have a solid answer here. I'm now using my own "structure" instead.

Comment: Then it sounds like you've solved your problem without needing outside help.

Comment: I'm just not sure if it was a smart workaround. Thanks for taking a look at my question in any case.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work as unity uses Mono and a subset of the core libraries, Windows is not going to be one of them.

Unity Rect has Contains and Overlaps to do logic tests for rects and points.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `System.Windows.Rect` I'd just write extension methods:

```
public static int left(this Rect rect) {
    return rect.x - rect.width * 0.5f;
}
public static int right(this Rect rect) {
    return rect.x + rect.width * 0.5f;
}
public static int top(this Rect rect) {
    return rect.y + rect.height * 0.5f;
}
public static int bottom(this Rect rect) {
    return rect.y - rect.height * 0.5f;
}
```

And write my own comparison extension method:

```
public static bool isEqualTo(this Rect rect, Rect otherRect) {
    return rect.x == otherRect.x && rect.y == otherRect.y &&
            rect.width == otherRect.width && rect.height == otherRect.height;
}
```